# EclipseLink 2.3 how to retrieve data from one table without joins

Tags: java, eclipselink

now i have problem i have 2 class employee and EmployeeDetials when i select from employee using jpa 2 Eclipselink that get employee with employee details from database how get employee without employee details . i used lazy fetching but it returned all data from emplyee and employee details

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste your relevant code here? Lazy loading means that data is loaded when it is first accessed. If you accessed it to check whether it was loaded or not you caused it was loaded.